# Rails Functional Tests - I can't assert a template from another controller's view in my functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

If controller A's action redirects to another controller B's action, can I check in A's functional test that B's action template is being rendered?

in controller As functional test
i.e. assert_template 'controllerB/some_view'

I know that this should be done in controllers Bs tests but I'm wondering if it is technically possible?

**I have tried this in my own project but it's failing so I wanted to know if its actually impossible to avoid wasting any time hunting down invisible bugs.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails functional tests do not follow redirects from one controller to another.  To test this you need to use an integration test.  The [Rails Guide for testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) can help you get started with integration tests

Comment: thanks tomtoday! you cleared up any doubts i had. Sometimes you wonder if its your own code, the machine or just the rules of the framework.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped.  I have spent more time that I care to admit on the very same problem.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

```
test "current/index should render others/action template" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "others/index"
end
```

Comment: sorry i never mentioned i was already trying this in my own project code but its failing.